# PostgreSQL - syntax error

Tags: postgresql

What is wrong with the following statement?

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO foo;
```

I get this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ALL"
LINE 2: ON ALL TABLES IN SCHEMA public TO foo;
```

I am using postgreSQL 8.3 on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your syntax is correct but only for PostgreSQL 9.0 and newer.
In 8.3 you will have to list all tables by name:

```
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON tab1, tab2, tab3 TO foo;
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, this is invalid in postgresql DB. You should grant the privileges on all tables by specifying them. The word `ALL` is invalid here.